# Can not get SQL Format file to work with BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

Im having troubles getting BULK import to work with a format file
I have a file with a couple of columns, the file is ; separated and had \R\N as row terminator.

I have created an formatfile by using bcp command. (I have tried both XML and fmt) it looks like this
[Screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBZqT.png)

My issue is that I keep getting errors no matter how I write the last terminator.
[Screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igROA.png)
I have tried: n, r, \r\n,\n, 0x0d 0x0a, \0x0d \0x0a, 0x0a  and \0x0a as shown in screendump
My query:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[bulk_LEDGERAUTHORISEDDIMREL]
 FROM 'D:\BCP TEST\Testfile\Relationships to authorized account plan.txt'
   WITH
     (
         FORMATFILE ='D:\BCP TEST\Formatfile\BLEDGERAUTHORISEDDIMREL.fmt',
         CODEPAGE='65001',
         FIRSTROW=2
      );
```

When the query runs with \0x0a in the format file I don’t get errors – but no rows are inserted

[Screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubhmj.png)

When I change the terminator to any other combination I get:

[Screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCiPT.png)

or

[Screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhtMo.png)

But when I skip the format file and run this:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[bulk_LEDGERAUTHORISEDDIMREL]
 FROM 'D:\BCP TEST\Testfile\Relationships to authorized account plan.txt'
   WITH
     (         
         CODEPAGE='65001',
         FIRSTROW=2,
         ROWTERMINATOR='0x0A',
         FIELDTERMINATOR='0X3B'
      );
```

Rows are inserted, but I need to use the format files to remove “ ” in some other files.
[Screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8evT.png)
Can anybody point me in any direction that would help men getting the format file to work?

Comment: If possible, I always recommend native format, as no format file is required.

Comment: _but I need to use the format files to remove “ ” in some other files_ you might be able to do this in SQL. Typically I just import text files as raw as possible (because so many inexplicable things can fail in the import process) then inspect and clean them up with T-SQL statements.

Comment: What version an edition of SQL Server are you using? There are various limitations on the `CODEPAGE` parameter, such as: being completely unsupported on SQL Server 2017 for Linux; not supporting code page 65001 (UTF-8) on versions period to SQL Server 2016; etc. Ref: [BULK INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid agree but some of the files are 17 MiO rows with 50 columns all text qualified so I would like to do this in the import if possible.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm using SQL 2019 standard.